# Creating a matrix over an image

Tags: python, pygame, nested-lists, grid-layout, pygame-surface

I decided to set the background image as the game board so that I wouldn't have to draw it every frame. The problem I am having now though it trying to create a matrix over this image in which the game pieces align where I want them. Not sure if I am doing this the most easy way, but here is what I have so far

[This is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoCUk.png)
[image]

```
import pygame
import HasamiShogiGame1


# CONSTANTS
width = 700
height = 700
SQUARE_SIZE = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

positions = {}
for row in range(9):
    for col in range(9):
        x = col * SQUARE_SIZE + 50
        y = row * SQUARE_SIZE + 50
        positions[row,col] = (x,y)

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Background Image and Scales to size
background = pygame.image.load("image/background.png")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (700,700))

# Create a HasamiShogiGame object and retrieve the game board
game = HasamiShogiGame1.HasamiShogiGame()
board = game.get_board()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    # Iterate through the game board and draw the pieces at their corresponding positions
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            value = board[row][col]
            pos = positions[row, col]
            if value == "B":
                pygame.draw.circle(background, (0, 0, 0), pos, SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 10)
            elif value == "R":
                pygame.draw.circle(background, (255, 0, 0), pos, SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 10)


    pygame.display.update()
```

I believe the pieces need to be shifted about 100 pixels but I don't know how I would approach that here. I'm not actually sure I'm going about doing this the most simplest way either

Comment: *"The problem I am having now though it trying to create a matrix over this image in which the game pieces align where I want them."* - Where do you want the game pieces to be? Please note that we cannot see the image.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I was wondering just in general how I would maneuver a matrix, be also here is what I am dealing with https://imgur.com/a/WBiA1WX

Answer (score 0):

The top left corner of the field "a1" of the grid on the image appears to be at (110, 130). The 3rd argument of [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) is the center of the circle. I suggest creating a grid of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and finding the center of the cell with the `center` attribute:

```py
grid_left = 110
grid_top = 130
positions = {}
for row in range(9):
    for col in range(9):
        x = col * SQUARE_SIZE + grid_left
        y = row * SQUARE_SIZE + grid_top
        positions[row,col] = pgame.Rect(x, y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
```

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            value = board[row][col]
            rect = positions[row, col]
            radius = SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 10
            if value == "B":
                pygame.draw.circle(background, (0, 0, 0), rect.center, radius)
            elif value == "R":
                pygame.draw.circle(background, (255, 0, 0), rect.center, radius)
```